# Pandas : read csv with embeded commas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a csv file with rows in the format :

```
A,B,"C,D",E
```

I want to have as an output :

```
   A   B  C,D   E
```

I used

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file_name',sep=",")
```

But it doesn't give the desired output.
Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file_name',sep=",",quotechar='"')
```

Specify the `quotechar` argument to `"`, then it will interprete everything between double quotes as part of a string (including the `,` character in the string).

Comment: I tried that but it still gives me all the row content in first column then the rest of columns are filled with NaN

Comment: Then you have to look at the file you want to read-in carefully. Is there a first row which is commented out?